# .Net core not reading appsettings after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

so shortly : 
I've got my startup class looking like this :

```
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
          .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat(
                "xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml"));
            options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat(
                "json", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        })
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

        var dbConfig = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DbOptions)).Get<DbOptions>();
        services.AddDbContext<GamesDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(dbConfig.ConnectionString));        
    }
```

And:
While i'm on localhost everything works just fine, but when i publish to web, app throws Status: 500 Internal server error on every request. I was wondering around and it turns out that if I replace

```
    var dbConfig = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DbOptions)).Get<DbOptions>();
    services.AddDbContext<GamesDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(dbConfig.ConnectionString));
```

with

```
    services.AddDbContext<GamesDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(@"connectionstring"));
```

It's working like a charm both locally and externally so i guess the problems lays in the parsing of appsettings.js, but what can be wrong with it ? appsettings.Development.json is basicaly just a copy-paste of appsettings.json

Comment: Can you share your appSettings after connection string cridential of course :D ?

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: @Rabur To get exact error you can add these two settings in your Application Settings

`ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS` = true and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` = `Development`.

This will give you detailed errors when you hit the APi with Postman. etc.

Comment: @ShaswatRungta@HenkMollema error says :ArgumentNullException
Parameter name: connectionString
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(string value, string parameterName)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(string value, string parameterName)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, string connectionString, Action<SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder> sqlServerOptionsAction)
GamesBoard.Startup<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<ConfigureServices>b__1(DbContextOptionsBuilder opt) in Startup.cs

Comment: @AdemCatamak it basically looks like this : 
{
  ...
  "DbOptions": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=mssql.SERWERPATH;Database=youknow;Uid=myUsername;Password=SecretStuff;",
    "DefaultSchema": "gb"
  },
  ...
}

Comment: @Rabur which version of .net core are you using?

Comment: @AntonToshik 2.0

Comment: @Rabur read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#add-configuration-providers see if putting the config init in `Program.cs` will help

Answer (score 1):

When I read code, I think your appSetting.Development.json structure look like that

```
{
    "DbOptions": {
         "connectionstrings": ""
     }
}
```

however, your appSetting.json structure look like that

```
{
     "connectionstrings": ""
}
```

I recommend to use like that

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DataContext": "Server=db;database=ProjectDb;uid=AppUser;pwd=AppPass;"
    },
    "Console": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
         }
    }
}
```

you can easily use like this.

```
string sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext");
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSql(sqlConnectionString));
```

In Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration class has extension for reading `ConnectionStrings`